# Go Exception "signal arrived during cgo execution"

Tags: windows, dll, go, ffi, cgo

In what circumstances Go panics like "**signal arrived during cgo execution**" when calling a **dll**?

The code to be called is - based on samples in `zsyscall_windows.go` in `src` of go distribution:

```
var (
    // entry names found using dumpbin /exports
    dllSweph = syscall.NewLazyDLL("swedll32.dll")

    _swe_jdut1_to_utc = dllSweph.NewProc("_swe_jdut1_to_utc@36")
    _swe_julday       = dllSweph.NewProc("_swe_julday@24")
)

func swe_julday(year, month, day int32, hour float64, gregflag int32) float64 {
    r, _, errn := syscall.Syscall6(
        _swe_julday.Addr(),
        5,
        uintptr(year),
        uintptr(month),
        uintptr(day),
        uintptr(hour),
        uintptr(gregflag),
        0)

    if r == 0 {
        if errn != 0 {
            panic(error(errn))
        }
    }

    return float64(r)
}

func swe_jdut1_to_utc(tjd_ut float64, gregflag int32, iyear, imonth, iday, ihour, imin *int32, dsec *float64) {
    defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
        }
    }()

    syscall.Syscall9(
        _swe_jdut1_to_utc.Addr(),
        8,
        uintptr(tjd_ut),
        uintptr(gregflag),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(iyear)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(imonth)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(iday)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(ihour)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(imin)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(dsec)),
        0)
}
```

Now when I call `swe_julday` everything seems to be fine; although it's not and it gives a wrong answer. And when `swe_jdut1_to_utc` is called, I get:

```
Exception 0xc0000005 0x1 0x42e5e5 0x3235ce40
PC=0x3235ce40
signal arrived during cgo execution

.../sweph.swe_jdut1_to_utc(0x40000000, 0x4150b979, 0x1, 0x1207bf24, 0x1207bf28, 0x1207bf34, 0x1207bf30, 0x1207bf2c, 0x1207bf38)
...(trace info)

eax     0x0
ebx     0x1207be94
ecx     0x1207bf38
edx     0x42e5e5
edi     0xcfeac
esi     0x0
ebp     0xcfe5c
esp     0xcfdd8
eip     0x3235ce40
eflags  0x10246
cs      0x23
fs      0x53
gs      0x2b
exit status 2

exit status 1
```

Environment:

```
Windows 8 x64
go 1.4    x86
gcc       x86
```

And I do not know if `gcc` is really needed to just call a dll, but I've installed it any way because the error was about `cgo`. All commands are in the path. Same error when compiling with administrative privileges.

The `C` function that is being called is:

```
void swe_jdut1_to_utc (double tjd_ut, int32 gregflag, int32 *iyear, int32 *imonth, int32 *iday, int32 *ihour, int32 *imin, double *dsec)
```

And the `C#` function which imports and calls this function in that dll (& works) is:

```
[DllImport("swedll32.dll", EntryPoint = "swe_jdut1_to_utc")]
public static extern void swe_jdut1_to_utc(
    double tjd_ut,
    int gregflag,
    ref Int32 iyear, ref Int32 imonth, ref Int32 iday,
    ref Int32 ihour, ref Int32 imin, ref double dsec);
```

Comment: 0xc0000005 is EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. It means somewhere in your program, you are trying to read / write memory that does not exist. For example reading at 0 address or similar. The problem is most likely because your syscall.Syscall9(_swe_jdut1_to_utc...) parameters do not match corresponding function arguments inside your DLL. You have to make sure that these two match exactly: parameter numbers and types.

Comment: Thanks @alex , I've done some more struggling and edited the question. I call the same `dll` from `C#` and `F#` (actually calls the `C#` wrappers) and it works fine and returns the right answers.

Comment: I'm no `C` expert but is it possible that `float64` in `Go` and `double` in `C` have different structure/definition/memory-layout?

Comment: I don't think so. Can I have your swedll32.dll to try your program?

Comment: @alex Sure, It's an open source project, whole source, samples and the compiled `dll` I use can be found in this zip file: http://www.astro.com/ftp/swisseph/sweph.zip

Comment: I managed to build delphi app that uses swe_julday function. Unfortunately I can see it uses fstp asm instruction to retrieve result returned by swe_julday. Go's syscall.Syscall does not support this functionality. You are our of luck. I think your best bet is to use CGO if it is possible to build your library with mingw compiler. Sorry.

Comment: @alex Thank you very much. You were the most helpful by providing a concrete conclusion. Now since wrestling with cgo and gcc is another matter, please post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the answer, for not more non-C/low-level-aware souls suffer by time and mind from this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to build delphi app that uses swe_julday function. Unfortunately I can see it uses fstp asm instruction to retrieve result returned by swe_julday. Go's syscall.Syscall does not support this functionality. You are our of luck. I think your best bet is to use CGO if it is possible to build your library with mingw compiler. Sorry

Alex

Comment: I've managed to compile the `C` code using gcc and make a single object file `swe.o`. Is it possible to use this object file + `.h` files with cgo? Using cgo directly with `C` source produces a plethora of error/warning messages and does not do the job after all.

Comment: I have answered your question here https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/PqJNf9fK0RQ/discussion Lets continue conversation there.